# Making Mezzanine Home Page editable

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

In urls.py there's a recipe how to make a home page that can be edited through admin:

```
# HOMEPAGE AS AN EDITABLE PAGE IN THE PAGE TREE
# ---------------------------------------------
# This pattern gives us a normal ``Page`` object, so that your
# homepage can be managed via the page tree in the admin. If you
# use this pattern, you'll need to create a page in the page tree,
# and specify its URL (in the Meta Data section) as "/", which
# is the value used below in the ``{"slug": "/"}`` part.
# Also note that the normal rule of adding a custom
# template per page with the template name using the page's slug
# doesn't apply here, since we can't have a template called
# "/.html" - so for this case, the template "pages/index.html"
# should be used if you want to customize the homepage's template.

url("^$", "mezzanine.pages.views.page", {"slug": "/"}, name="home"),
```

So,

1) I create a page named 'home' in admin with url '/' in metadata section

2) I uncomment `url("^$", "mezzanine.pages.views.page", {"slug": "/"}, name="home"),` in urls.py of my site

And after this I get a Mezzanine-style page with 'Error' and no specific info.

How I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I did some mistake first - maybe, I named the page in admin wrong.

Then on some point I've copy-pasted a patch from https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine to mezzanine own files (usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mezzanine/...).

And while I did this, my vim profile didn't substitute 1 tab for 4 spaces. And this costed me 3h of pain )

After I replaced tabs with spaces in the place where I messed with mezzanine (usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mezzanine/pages/views.py), everything went ok.

So:

1) follow the urls.py recipe

2) name editable homepage in admin 'home' (I also made it RichTextPage - don't know if other types work)

3) have correct .vimrc profile

4) be careful when tinkering with mezzanine code and applying patches

my current .vimrc vim profile -> [link](https://gist.github.com/ddsherstennikov/586efd649dd29d69cdb1)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you start off fresh and never modify the code in usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mezzanine/.  It will have undesirable results and will also break future update.

Uncomment the line in the URLs

Create any page with the url of / in the meta section

Read this too:
http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/frequently-asked-questions.html#why-isn-t-the-homepage-a-page-object-i-can-edit-via-the-admin

Comment: thx, done all this.

maybe will have to reinstall mezz sometime, but for now it's dev deploy, so I tinkered.